# Friend declaration and explicit template instantiation declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, explicit-instantiation

Suppose I have a function template

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) {}
```

Then, we could have a friend declaration

```
friend void f<int>(int);
```

and an explicit template instantiation declaration

```
extern template void f<int>(int);
```

Are the two declarations related in some way or totally independent? If related, how do they interact with each other?

Comment: Define _related_  in more detail please. `friend` declarations are not the same or somehow related to `extern` declarations. Do you have a certain standard section in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `friend` declaration doesn't "interact" with any thing, other than the definition of the function which is declared to be a friend, which is allowed to access private members of the class containing the declaration.

So, no, there is no special interaction between the `friend` declaration and the `extern template` declaration, although they both refer to the same function (in this sense, they are related, but I assume you realised this when you wrote the question).

Comment: Wouldn't a friend declaration with such explicit template arguments be considered an implicit instantiation? That would be almost related to an explicit instantiation (without the `extern`).

Comment: @0x499602D2 I see what you are saying, but I don't think it does qualify as an implicit instantiation. g++ seems to agree with me - a quick test shows that no instantiation is emitted.

Comment: From the spec: a "function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist"

Comment: @davmac I'm wondering why the term *specialization* is used in the quoted spec. I think it should have nothing to do with template specialization anyway.

Comment: @Lingxi I gather that the spec refers to any template with type arguments applied as a specialization. A specialization providing an alternative definition is an _explicit_ specialization: "An explicit specialization may be declared for a function template, a class template, a member of a class template or a member template. An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by template<>"